# Won't print if I feedback into a function

Tags: python, printing

So I have some code where I create a list at the start and then ask a user if he wants to make an object (turtle), in which case it adds that to the list, OR if he wants to move the turtle (X). If the user has not created the object I want it to print 'Need to create object'. Here is the code.

```
adventurousch = []

def RoamingTurtles(): 
   command = raw_input("---> ")
   if command == 'A':
     newAdventureTurtle()
     RoamingTurtles() 
   if command == 'X':
    if adventurousch == []:
      print "Need to create object"
      RoamingTurtles()
    else:
      for i in adventurousch:
        i.drawSquare()
        print "test"
```

If I have no RoamingTurtles() after the print then it prints out successfully. i.e

```
if command == 'X':
    if adventurousch == []:
      print "Need to create object"
```

But if I add it in then it no longer prints. i.e

```
if command == 'X':
    if adventurousch == []:
        print "Need to create object"
        RoamingTurtles()
```

Shouldn't it print the statement first then feedback into the function? I am confused. I want it to print'Need to create object' then feedback into the function so they can create the object.

Comment: Not your problem here, but this is a really bad design. Each time you get a new command, you're calling yourself recursively, and never returning anywhere. So, you're just building the stack up higher and higher until you get a `RecursionError`.

Comment: Also, when I run this code, exactly as-is, it already does exactly what you're asking for. See [this transcript](http://pastebin.com/hWdfp2pn).

Comment: Yeah I'm new to programming so I don't even know what you mean by your first comment. But I have copied and pasted it and it isn't printing.

Comment: @Danrex: Recursive means a function calling itself. The code in the `RoamingTurtles()` function does this whenever `command` is equal to `'A'` or `'X'` (after it does something else first). When this happens you'll see the `--->` prompt from `raw_input()` appear again because the function starts at its beginning each time.

Comment: Thanks Martineau! I thought that is what they mean't. So what would be the best way to stop it?

Answer (score 0):

Your code already *does* print `Need to create object` each time you enter `X` at the prompt. See this ipython transcript:

```
In [41]: %cpaste
Pasting code; enter '--' alone on the line to stop or use Ctrl-D.
:adventurousch = []
:
:def RoamingTurtles():
:   command = raw_input("---> ")
:   if command == 'A':
:     newAdventureTurtle()
:     RoamingTurtles()
:   if command == 'X':
:    if adventurousch == []:
:      print "Need to create object"
:      RoamingTurtles()
:    else:
:      for i in adventurousch:
:        i.drawSquare()
:        print "test"
:<EOF>

In [42]: RoamingTurtles()
---> X
Need to create object
---> X
Need to create object
---> X
Need to create object
--->
```

So, if your actual code is different from the code you posted… just use the code you posted, which works.*

---

* Well, it works as far as this particular problem.

Comment: I have copied and pasted it and it doesn't print for me